# what is the best way to keep image's data when modifying?

Tags: c#, image

In my project, i have to resize the image and then save it to a folder. I have posted many questions to find out what method can resize the image without distory the image, but i still not find the best method..

For testing the method, I don't try to resize the image but output an 100% size of the image in resize method.

**resize method:**

```
    public Image reduce(Image sourceImage, string size)
    {
        //for testing, i want to use the size of the source image
        //double percent = Convert.ToDouble(size) / 100;
        int width = (int)(sourceImage.Width); //sourceImage.Width * percent 
        int height = (int)(sourceImage.Height); //sourceImage.Height *percent 
        var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

        destImage.SetResolution(sourceImage.HorizontalResolution, sourceImage.VerticalResolution);
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
        {
            graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
            {
                wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
                graphics.DrawImage(sourceImage, destRect, 0, 0, sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
            }
        }

        return destImage;
    }
```

using:

```
//the code to get the image is omitted (in my testing, jpg format is fixed, however, other image formats are required)
//to test the size of original image
oImage.Save(Path.Combine(oImagepath), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

Image nImage = resizeClass.reduce(oImage,"100");
nImage .Save(Path.Combine(nImagepath), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Result:

> - The first saving of the image:    fileSize: **10721KB**
> - The second saving of the image:   fileSize: **4033KB** <= it should be 10721KB

The problem is how can the user accept to receive a 4 MB image if they pass a 10MB image by setting 90% - 100%? It is ridiculous, so i have to rewrite the program :(

**Image:**

original: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AsdOBLg50clihVaoEQdj1wQidhdX

resized: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AsdOBLg50clihVV96AVKouVkI25o

Comment: It's most probably a result of jpeg compression. Why does it bother you that much? Try [setting compression level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) of saved file.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you are saving the image out with JPEG compression. While JPEG does have a [lossless compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG) it is a completely different algorithm and most encoders do not support it. Try using a lossless image format such as PNG.

From the [Lossless compression wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression):

> Lossless compression is a class of data compression algorithms that allows the original data to be perfectly reconstructed from the compressed data
>
> By contrast, lossy compression permits reconstruction only of an approximation of the original data, though this usually improves compression rates (and therefore reduces file sizes).

So if you don't mind losing some of the pixel data when you save, you can still use JPEG but you will need to specify a higher Quality value in order to keep more of the information stored in the image after the save.

As slawekwin mentioned in his comment, check out the following article on [setting compression levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
Try using this code to set the quality to 100% thus receiving a much better quality image (but note this is still not lossless):

```
EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters(); 
ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, (long)100);
```